# Sam local with NodeJS - where does request spend so much time

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have written a NodeJS lambda function and I am testing it locally with `sam local`. I have noticed the browser takes much more time to download it than I can see the lambda execution from the logs. Chrome shows that it waited 6,13 seconds before the server responded.

```
2020-02-04 21:02:18 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2020 21:02:18] "GET /v1/verify/Yk6QwCF1 HTTP/1.1" 502 -
Invoking src/handlers/users/verifyUser.handler (nodejs10.x)
Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x Docker container image......
Mounting C:\dev\mezinamiridici\infrastructure as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
?[32mREPORT RequestId: 56060b6c-2bef-1241-03a4-fb2fca321096     Init Duration: 2238.80 ms       
Duration: 127.36 ms     Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 59 MB  ?[0m
2020-02-04 21:03:10 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2020 21:03:10] "GET /v1/verify/Yk6QwCF1 HTTP/1.1" 403 -
```

It should be some 2,5 seconds. Where are the remaining almost 4 seconds spent?

[image: Chrome network timing]

The source code is there: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/infrastructure/src/handlers/users/verifyUser.js

Comment: Finding: sam local start-api --skip-pull-image will save two seconds .. See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/239. But I am still at 4 seconds

Comment: Where is your database?

Comment: Localhost. I can see that the lambda execution is under 200 ms.

Comment: Can you add the `--debug` option and have a look where the logs are "hanging" when waiting for the request to respond? Does this also happen when you consecutively request your function or does it only happen for the first request?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try. Yes, it happens even if I run it again within few seconds. The time is the same.

Comment: Debug does not show the time :-( I submitted an enhancement https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1773

Comment: Does it fetch the docker image in every request? That's weird.

Comment: Network latency? Can you please try the same code with some other ISP?

Comment: Network latency on 127.0.0.1 should be 0.

Comment: Are you running the command through any NICs or switches?

Comment: No, it is plain localhost.